# PC actin gpretty slow and low FPS in games Ive never had any trouble with

Tags: performance

so about 2 days ago my pc started to feel a little slow, but not anything that's very alarming. Yesterday, I tried playing Rainbow Six Siege which is a game I have been playing for a long time now and I kept getting 20 ~ 30 fps which is nowhere near what I usually get. I tried playing other games and all of them were the same - very low fps. I checked Task Manager while playing and they all had one thing in common - Power Usage was "Very High", Other than that, CPU, RAM, and GPU were all doing fine. I have looked all around the internet and nothing has helped me so far, I even tried reinstalling windows but that didn't help either. I am playing on an HP OMEN laptop with a GTX 1050, i7-7700HQ, and 12 GB of RAM. I know these specs are not that good nowadays but, as I said, these games worked great earlier. Thank you for reading this, hope I can get this fixed soon.

Comment: Heatsink come loose? Check CPU and GPU temperatures using something like `hwinfo`.

Comment: I checked CPU and GPU temperature using CoreTemp and MSI Afterburner and they were both normal

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While I don't have a solution, here are some tips to make it more likely to attract answers: (1) Add paragraphs (press enter twice) to make your post easier to read. (2) Mention what you changed something 2 days ago or say you didn't change anything.

If you find the answer yourself: post it here for future visitors.